# Excel IF Statement Limited

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, office365

I am using an IF statement in Excel to search for portions of text in the previous column in order to assign a supplier and category to the expense.

**Supplier Column**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("tit",[@Description])),"TITAN",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sol",[@Description])),"Soltrack",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("coin",[@Description])),"Coin",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("gree",[@Description])),"Green Dream Projects",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sars V",[@Description])),"SARS VAT",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sars p",[@Description])),"SARS PAYE",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("acb",[@Description])),"Debit Order","")))))))
```

**Category Column**

the next column then has the following to get the category of the supplier

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TITAN",[@Payee])),"Direct Operating Cost",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Soltrack",[@Payee])),"Direct Operating Cost",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Coin",[@Payee])),"Direct Operating Cost",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Green Dream Projects",[@Payee])),"Direct Operating Cost",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SARS VAT",[@Payee])),"VAT",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SARS PAYE",[@Payee])),"PAYE",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Debit Order",[@Payee])),"Debit Order","")))))))
```

this is working great, but seems i have reached the limit (7) of IF statements I can use in one formula?

I have created the below function to search for text "*tit*" and if it matches it updates the Payee column.

```
'excel if range of cells contains specific text vba
Sub MacroToCheckIfRangeOfCellsContainsSpecificText_vba()

Set Rng = Range("B2:B572") ' You can change this
specificText = "*tit*" ' You can change this


 For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
 
 If UCase(Cell.Value) Like "*" & UCase(specificText) & "*" Then
 Cell.Offset(0, 1) = "Titan"
 Else
 Cell.Offset(0, 1) = ""
 End If
 Next
 
End Sub
```

Would I need to create a new  `specificText = "*tit*"` for each of the keywords and also a whole section for each of the "For Each" functions?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can create own function and have no limits :) https://trumpexcel.com/user-defined-function-vba/

Comment: Here is the official documentation of how to [Create custom functions in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f).

Comment: Can you show some sample data? There may other way to achieve your output. `Excel365` have few dynamic formulas which can shorter other version legacy formula.

Comment: From your formula assuming you can use `Xlookup()` with `Wildcard` option.

Comment: @Harun24HR   sure.   https://1drv.ms/x/s!AuYEj8XY5PI_hKk7G_Nn99mrDKBQBw?e=l7UrEr  plz confirm you can open this? thank you

Comment: @anna instead of files please always include screenshots. Links will disappear or not work in the future and so the question gets useless to future readers.

Comment: It doesn't look like you actually need a partial search at all, so a simple lookup table and `VLOOKUP` would do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Dictionary Solution

The first idea is to use a dictionary `Replacements` and add all the serach/replace pairs there. This has one huge disadvantage. It is against the good practice to not mix logic (code) and data. Good practice would be to put the data not into the code but into a worksheet (see next solution).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MacroToCheckIfRangeOfCellsContainsSpecificText_vba()
    Dim RngToCheck As Range
    Set RngToCheck = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B572") ' specify in which workbook and worksheet
    
    Dim Replacements As Object
    Set Replacements = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With Replacements
        .Add "tit", "Titan"
        .Add "sol", "Soltrack"
        'add more here
    End With
    
    Dim InputValues() As Variant
    InputValues = RngToCheck.Value 'read input values into array
    
    Dim OutputValues() As Variant 'create an output array (same size as RngToCheck)
    ReDim OutputValues(1 To RngToCheck.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To UBound(OutputValues, 1)
        Dim Key As Variant
        For Each Key In Replacements.Keys
            If UCase(InputValues(iRow, 1)) Like "*" & UCase(Key) & "*" Then
                OutputValues(iRow, 1) = Replacements(Key)
                Exit For 'we don't need to test for the others if we found a key
            End If
        Next Key
    Next iRow
    
    'write output values from array next to input values in the cells
    RngToCheck.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = OutputValues
End Sub
```

#### Worksheet Solution

The better solution would be to create a new worksheet `Replacements` as below:
[image]

This can easily be edited by anyone and you don't need to fiddle with the code later if you want to delete or add pairs.

```
Public Sub ImprovedCheckUsingWorksheet()
    Dim RngToCheck As Range
    Set RngToCheck = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B572") ' specify in which workbook and worksheet
    
    Dim Replacements() As Variant 'read replacements from worksheet
    Replacements = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Replacements").Range("A2", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value 'read input values into array
    
    
    Dim InputValues() As Variant
    InputValues = RngToCheck.Value 'read input values into array
    
    Dim OutputValues() As Variant 'create an output array (same size as RngToCheck)
    ReDim OutputValues(1 To RngToCheck.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To UBound(OutputValues, 1)
        Dim rRow As Long
        For rRow = 1 To UBound(Replacements, 1)
            If UCase(InputValues(iRow, 1)) Like "*" & UCase(Replacements(rRow, 1)) & "*" Then
                OutputValues(iRow, 1) = Replacements(rRow, 2)
                Exit For 'we don't need to test for the others if we found a key
            End If
        Next rRow
    Next iRow
    
    'write output values from array next to input values in the cells
    RngToCheck.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = OutputValues
End Sub
```

For a 3ʳᵈ column in your replacements worksheet you would need to adjust the following line to be until column `"C"`:

```
Replacements = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Replacements").Range("A2", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Value 'read input values into array
```

and the output values need another column too (second parameter needs to go `1 To 2`):

```
ReDim OutputValues(1 To RngToCheck.Rows.Count, 1 To UBound(Replacements, 2) - 1) 'this works for any amount of columns as it reads the column count from the `Replacements`
```

the data needs to be written

```
OutputValues(iRow, 1) = Replacements(rRow, 2) 'first output column
OutputValues(iRow, 2) = Replacements(rRow, 3) 'second output column
```

and writing the output values needs to be adjusted too:

```
RngToCheck.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(ColumnSize:=UBound(OutputValues, 2)).Value = OutputValues 'this works for any amount of columns as it reads the column count from `OutputValues`
```

#### Formula Solution

But if you have your data in a worksheet `Replacements` like above, and you don't rely an a partial match. Then you don't need VBA and can easily use a formula instead to look it up:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Replacements!B:B,MATCH(B:B,Replacements!A:A,0)),"")
```

Comment: Thank you ! The Worksheet solution works perfectly using a sheet called "Replacements", thank you.  would it be hard for a 3rd column to be used in the replacements sheet called 'category' - for the expense category to just copy to the first sheet?

Comment: @Anna see my edited answer for more columns.

Comment: Thank you ! this is perfect and is working 100%.  thank you